# Systemd boot ordering: Wait for mysql.sock

Tags: mysql, systemd

I have an openvpn tunnel which runs an `--up` script which queries a local mysql database for IP routing information and then applies the routes. However, since both the openvpn and mysql systemd services are configured with the `After=network.target` directive, I have a race condition: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock might exist when the `--up` script runs, or it might not. If the sock file doesn't exist, then my script dies and the system doesn't initialize properly.

I thought that changing my openvpn.service directive to `After=network.target mysql.service` and running `systemctl daemon-reload` would do the trick. However, I added `ls -lh /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` to the beginning of my `--up` script, and it still sometimes reports `ls: cannot access '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock': No such file or directory`.

My guess is that systemd's is not using the sock file to determine whether or not mysqld has finished loading but rather some criteria that happens before the sock file is created.

Is there a way to tell systemd to not recognize mysql.service as having started until the sock file has been created?

Comment: Of course, I could start my script with a wait loop which checks for the sock file and sleeps repeatedly until it has been created, but that sounds like a hack especially if systemd can be configured to do it for me.

Comment: From what source did you install MySQL?

Comment: A wait loop is probably your best option on the user side. I did briefly explore the possibility of starting the socket before starting MySQL but I can't see evidence that it would work.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, start some other service after mysql started

First i disable my service

```
systemctl disable rfid-server
```

After that i modified my rfid-server.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=rfid server
After=mysql.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/rfid-server-service/deploy/start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target mysql.service
```

An the i re-enable my service

```
systemctl enable /complete/path/to/service

Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/rfid-server.service to /opt/rfid-server-service/rfid-server.service.
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.wants/rfid-server.service to /opt/rfid-server-service/rfid-server.service.
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/rfid-server.service to /opt/rfid-server-service/rfid-server.service.
```

As you can see, it create the symlink to mysql.service.wants

Answer (score 0):

May be you should add `ConditionPathExists` check in your service file?

There is quote from systemd [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html):

> With ConditionPathExists= a file existence condition is checked before
>   a unit is started. If the specified absolute path name does not exist,
>   the condition will fail. If the absolute path name passed to
>   ConditionPathExists= is prefixed with an exclamation mark ("!"), the
>   test is negated, and the unit is only started if the path does not
>   exist.

Comment: Hmm. Searching for ConditionPathExists led me to this similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388483/delay-systemd-service-if-file-exist Although it looks like it checks and waits exactly once and then blindly runs desired command without checking again.